# I have an array and I want to eliminate every mutiple occurences item, and want back to print only non-multiple occurence elements of array

Tags: javascript

let arr = [100, 123, 100, 122, 119, 203, 123, 76, 89]
through JavaScript I want my output should be-

- [122,119,203,76,89]

I tried filter method-

```
const arr= [100, 123, 100, 122, 119, 203, 123, 76, 89]

const removeNo = (data) => {
    return data.filter((val, ind) => data.indexOf(val) === ind);
}
console.log(removeNo(num))
```

Comment: what should the output if you call `console.log(removeNo(123))` ?

Comment: The requirement is not clear. Do you want to eliminate the number you passed in function with multiple occurences ? or do you want to eliminate all the multiple occurences of all the numbers ? or you just want to eliminate the number you passed ?

Comment: I want to eliminate all the multiple occurences of all the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try filtering all element that their `indexOf` and [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf) are the same value, meaning it only has one occurance in the array.

```js
const arr= [100, 123, 100, 122, 119, 203, 123, 76, 89]

const removeNo = (data) => {
    return data.filter((val) => data.indexOf(val) === data.lastIndexOf(val));
}

console.log(removeNo(arr))
```

---

### Explain

`indexOf` searches the index an element from the left side of an array, while `lastIndexOf` searches starting from the right side.

Imagine an array, that we want to find all elements without duplicates.

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

Using `filter` function, we are iterating every element throughout the array.

1. On the first iteration, it checks the first array which is `1`

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
 ^ <- filter pointer
```

2. Then `indexOf` searches `1` from the left side, which is also the **first** element

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
 ^ 
 ^ <- indexOf pointer
```

3. Since it found the target element from the left side, now it's time to find the same element `1` from the right side with `lastIndexOf`, which is the **fourth** element

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
 ^ 
 ^ 
          ^ <- lastIndexOf pointer
```

4. Counting from the left side, `1` is found on the first position. But while counting from the right side, `1` is found on the fourth position. Which does not match the previous search, so the first element `1` fails the test.
5. The second element also fails the test due to the same reason.

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
    ^ <- filter pointer
    ^ <- indexOf pointer
             ^ <- lastIndexOf pointer
```

6. While on the third iteration, both searches lands on the same index, so it is confident to say `3` is unique in this array.

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
       ^ <- filter pointer
       ^ <- indexOf pointer
       ^ <- lastIndexOf pointer
```

7. Then the rest of the elements also fail the test using the same logic.

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
          ^ <- filter pointer
 ^ <- indexOf pointer
          ^ <- lastIndexOf pointer
```

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
             ^ <- filter pointer
    ^ <- indexOf pointer
             ^ <- lastIndexOf pointer
```

8. So only the third element `3` passes the test, the output is `[3]`.

Hope this helps you understanding this approach.

Comment: but can you explain it please briefly....... I am bit confused, it will more help me ...

Comment: @Manish I added the explaination, forgive my non-native English but hope it helps you to understand.

Comment: Seriously man, am huge fan of yours, you literally a dope in programming, and your way of explaination is far good too. I thoroughly understand it. And in future too, more questions I am bringing in front of you. Thanks!!!